# Bounce Text one by one in regular interval of time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to code a bouncing effect with text, to make it bounce one by one in regular interval just as a marquee.

I've tried with jquery but not getting it to bounce one by one.

Here is my [`FIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/jb9mt/1).

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".test").effect( "bounce", 
              {times:4}, 500 );

});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="test">
    <p>First Time Bounce</p>
    <p>This Bounce to nxt(After First)</p>

    .
    .
    .
    <p>Last Bounce Then return To First One</p>
</div>
```

Comment: please post code here as well, fiddle is for giving us a live example of code

Comment: What do you mean by "one by one"? Are you trying to get the individual letters to bounce?

Comment: Please don't try to sidestep the SO rule of posting code here when posting links to jsFiddle.net.

Comment: yes on by one means, suppose i have 2 texts

Comment: @user2726702: That doesn't answer the question. What do you mean by "2 texts" do you mean two strings? Or two letters?

Answer (score 1):

If you update your HTML to have some type of wrapper element around each letter, you can animate each in turn. Then you just need to loop through the letters and animate them one at a time.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //setup a counter to keep our place and cache a selection to the letter wrappers
    var counter = 0,
        $chars  = $(".test").children();

    //setup an interval to animate a letter every so often
    setInterval(function () {

        //select the current letter wrapper and animate it
        $chars.eq(counter).effect( "bounce", {times:1}, 500 );

        //increment the counter so we animate the next letter next time around
        counter++;

        //check if the counter still relates to an index of the $chars collection
        if (counter >= $chars.length) {
            counter = 0;
        }
    }, 250);

});
```

This assumes HTML structure like so:

```
<div class="test">
    <span>s</span>
    <span>o</span>
    <span>m</span>
    <span>e</span> 
    <span>t</span>
    <span>e</span>
    <span>x</span>
    <span>t</span>
</div>
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jb9mt/6/

Note that I had to update the CSS for the jQueryUI wrapper element added to the HTML structure when using the `bounce` effect (`ui-effects-wrapper`) to display inline:

```
.ui-effects-wrapper {
    display : inline-block;
}
```

Comment: @user2726702 My suggestion will work, just put more than one letter in the `<span>` elements and change the `<span>`s to `<p>`s if you want.

Comment: ya but i don't want all text together to be shown, i ant to show it one by one as a slider u can say but each should come from top to bottom and must bounce while dropping down. hoe u get now what i am looking for.

Comment: @user2726702 Then you should update your question, you don't mention that at all. If you want to get an exact effect I recommend finding it somewhere else as a demo because I'm not quite getting what you mean.

Comment: see as the page loads firstly a text appears, then after an interval, the first one (on page load text)should get disappear and the next text should come from top to bottom,bounces when reach to bottom.